# Inserting CSV to sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, csv

I have a csv file that has two columns. I created a database called beacon, which takes col1 and col2. I have tried two different ways, one using pandas and one without. Both ways allow me to read the csv file fine, but I don't think they're actually adding those two columns into my database!

#### First Method

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

conn = sqlite3.connect('MyDB.db')  
c = conn.cursor()

read_beacon = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/seifeldeen/Downloads/BeaconID&ACID.csv')
read_beacon.to_sql('beacon', conn, if_exists= 'append', index = False)
conn.commit()
df = DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=['col1','col2'])
print (df)
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'/Users/seifeldeen/Downloads/export_list.csv', index = None,         header=True)
```

#### Second Method

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db'")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (col1, col2);") 

with open('BeaconID&ACID.csv','r') as fin: 
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin) # comma is default delimiter
    to_db = [(i['col1'], i['col2']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO n (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?);", to_db)
con.commit()
con.close
```

Also, I made sure that the csv columns and the beacon table use the same column names. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you check if the data is written to db is a bit flawed in:
`df = DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=['col1','col2'])`

You never executed a query using the cursor (c) and tried using c.fetchall(). This will always return empty list [].

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

df.to_sql('test', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
conn.commit()

cursor.execute('SELECT * from test')
cursor.fetchall() # this should return a list of all entries in your db
```